# Getting a pattern in regex

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to capture the following pattern:

`&lt;a href="http://cdn.xyz.com/media/info.pdf" target="_blank"&gt;`

This is what I am trying:

```
preg_match_all( '/(&lt;[a-zA-Z]+[^&gt;]+&gt;)/ism', $str, $matches);
```

This is not capturing the above pattern.

How should I restructure the pattern.

Thanks

Comment: what's your expected output?

Comment: The anchor tag which is given above. It is a part of a larger string.

Comment: Perhaps `/&lt;.+?&gt;/ism`? Not clear what you need. By the way, you shouldn't be using regular expressions to parse HTML, it won't work for every case.

Comment: @Havenard It helped.  Can you post this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could to use a negative lookahead assertion based regex.

```
preg_match_all('~&lt;[a-zA-Z]+(?:(?!&[lg]t;).)*&gt;~isg', $str, $matches);
```

`(?:(?!&[lg]t;).)*` matches any character but not of `&lt;` or `&gt;`. That is, it checks whether the character going to be matched won't be the starting letter in `&lt;` or `&gt;`.

**OR**

```
&lt;[a-zA-Z]+.*?&gt;
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/jE8sO0/2)

Comment: Negative lookahead is not necessary in this case, a lazy plus will do the same work.

Comment: it's must. see https://regex101.com/r/jE8sO0/3 and https://regex101.com/r/jE8sO0/4

Comment: @avinash-raj It works, but the solution proposed by Havenard is much more simpler. Thanks for the help though and +1 for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
(&lt;[a-zA-Z]+.+?&gt;)
```

You can use this simple pattern.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/bW3aR1/14

Your regex contains `[^&gt;]+` which is not what you think.It is just a class of characters which should not appear.The order is not defined over here.